# WPF Change EllipseGeometry RadiusX and RadiusY on Mouse Over

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hi I have a circle and sort of want it to have a popout effect when hovering over it. Way to do it is by sizing the radius on mouse over. So I have this basically:

```
<DataTemplate>
<Path x:Name="border" Grid.Row="0" Fill="{Binding Value.Situation, Converter={StaticResource SituationCodeToBrushConverter}}" Stretch="Fill">
   <Path.Data>
       <GeometryGroup FillRule="EvenOdd">
           <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="44" RadiusY="44" Center="50,50" />
                                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,100,100" />
       </GeometryGroup>
   </Path.Data>
</Path>

<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource BrightBlueBrush}"/>
    </Trigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

You will notice via the Trigger I am able to fill the circle with a color on mouse over, but how do I get down into the EllipseGeometry  to change the RadiusX and RadiusY

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't directly access the EllipseGeometry in a Trigger of the DataTemplate, you could revert to the hacky trick of using the Path's `Tag` property:

```
<Path x:Name="border" Tag="44" ...>
    <Path.Data>
        <GeometryGroup FillRule="EvenOdd">
            <EllipseGeometry Center="50,50"
                             RadiusX="{Binding Tag,ElementName=border}"
                             RadiusY="{Binding Tag,ElementName=border}"/>
            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,100,100" />
        </GeometryGroup>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Now can set the `Tag` value in a Setter:

```
<Setter Property="Tag" TargetName="border" Value="50"/>
```